# If the Benn Act effectively prevents a no deal exit on October 31st, why delay a general election?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union

The [European Union
(Withdrawal) (No. 2)
Act 2019](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2019/26/pdfs/ukpga_20190026_en.pdf) (the "Benn Act") effectively prevents a no-withdrawal-agreement Brexit on October 31st.

The Remain side are currently refusing to permit Boris Johnson to hold a general election, seemingly on the basis that he might use the provisions of the [Fixed Term Parliament Act](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2011/14/pdfs/ukpga_20110014_en.pdf) to bump the UK in to a no-withdrawal-agreement exit.

But the Benn Act precludes this. What am I missing?